# What firmware parts non opensource (yet)?

Tags: firmware, open-source

What parts of the RaspberryPi (A,B,B+) are not open-source (yet)? I mean **any** part of the device which requires some kind of software to run.

Answer (score 4):

GPU requires a non-free binary blob. Moreover, unlike on desktop computers, you cannot avoid using it even if you do not need graphics at all – due to design, Raspberry Pi just would not start without that blob.

Since it’s quite large for firmware: about 2 Mb¹ (in binary form, of course), I doubt, that it would be been legally reversed some day and thus free/libre implementation would be written.

---

<sup>¹ For comparison: non-free blobs required for Radeon HD 8[1-4]00 series are about 60 **k**b large.</sup>

---

P. S. Actually, when early in 2014 [rpi.o announced](http://www.raspberrypi.org/a-birthday-present-from-broadcom/) good news which gave ability [to use](http://www.raspberrypi.org/quake-iii-bounty-we-have-a-winner/) a free/libre graphics *driver* (yes, much more non-free software was needed before), *in comments* Liz Upton said that they were *“going to be working on a minimal, open [source replacement for the] blob so you’ll be able to boot without it, but that won’t happen for a while; it’ll be a fair amount of work”*. But I have not heard about any progress on this task.

Comment: Broadcom opened this up a few months back. [source](http://blog.broadcom.com/chip-design/android-for-all-broadcom-gives-developers-keys-to-the-videocore-kingdom/) also for official rpi [blog](http://www.raspberrypi.org/a-birthday-present-from-broadcom/)

Comment: @geoffmcc No. That blogpost has nothing to do with the blob I am talking about.

Comment: @geoffmcc Actually, *in comments* they said that they are _“going to be working on a minimal, open [source replacement for the] blob so you’ll be able to boot without it, but that won’t happen for a while; it’ll be a fair amount of work”_. Do you know how they are progressing in that?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they did it as there was a contest to see who could get quake to work first, it was done and the competition closed, so I thought it was a done deal and part of latest firmware

Comment: @geoffmcc They did **what**? You are using RPi without non-free blobs now?

Comment: I guess not. I thought it was rolled out in an update here is a post about the 10k bounty winner and steps he used to get quake to use the opensourced gpu with framerate of at least 20. [Post](http://www.raspberrypi.org/quake-iii-bounty-we-have-a-winner/)

Comment: @geoffmcc What do you mean by ‘opensourced gpu’? In March free/libre 3d-graphics *driver* had became available. Are you sure, that you understand the difference between a *driver* and a *firmware*?

Comment: My bad, looks like was a kernel module and not firmware (although I could have sworn it was added to firmware).  Sorry about the down vote. I would take it back if it would let me

Comment: @geoffmcc By the way, thanks for the info that you pointed out to me :-); maybe someday they would indeed make RPi usable without non-free firmware. I’ve updated the answer (thus now StackExchange shall let you change the vote if you wish so).

Comment: Done, as it was a well written, correct answer.